# How to serialize a Java comparator into JSON?

Tags: java, serialization

I'm currently building a program in which Java objects are serialized to JSON on the client and then deserialized back to Java objects and processed on the server. I've implemented serialization properly for most common `Collection` subclasses, but I'm struggling to figure out what to do about `TreeMap` instances that rely on custom instances of `Comparator`.

In particular, how could a custom `Comparator` like this one be serialized?

```
Comparator<String> lengthComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.length(), o2.length());
    }
};
```

I'm mainly trying to figure out how this could be serialized into JSON at the client and then deserialized at the server in the case where this anonymous subclass of `Comparator` was not already defined at the server.

Comment: The comparator has no state, so there is nothing really to serialize except the binary name of the anonymous class. Like any other class, the anonymous class needs to exist in the classpath of whichever JVM it's deserialized on. If you want to implement the `Serializable` interface, you probably need to declare it as a non-anonymous class with an `implements` clause.

Comment: I think you might have a misconception about Java serialization. In order to be deserialized you still need the appropriate libraries at the target, including your custom comparator. Only the information necessary to hydrate an instance of a class is serialized.

Comment: @DaveNewton, thanks that answered my secondary question about how Java serialization works. I'll edit my question to remove that part since I'm mainly interested in getting this to work with JSON.

Comment: That's just a specific serialization format (searchable). The comparator doesn't really come in to the picture at all--you just need the appropriate library on the target.

Comment: @DaveNewton hmm, I reread that last comment five times, but I don't think I quite understand. What library do you mean? Are you talking about something like jackson or gson ?

Comment: If you want to reconstruct the whole object tree your JSON must include the whole class hierarchy not only the values. Or you supply a custom serializer which reads the type of comparator from the stream. But be careful that's not only a security problem but also makes stability of the interface very brittle.

Comment: There are two separate topics in my comment. 1) serialization to JSON--use a library, or roll your own. However it's done the target will need to deserialize JSON, likely with the same library. 2) Comparator "serialization"--irrelevant; there's nothing to serialize: you need the comparator on the target as well. All you're serializing/deserializing are your data structures, not your code.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for clarifying. I now completely understand point 2. As for point 1, I'm trying to roll my own for this very specific use case - that's why I asked the question, haha. I'm happy to edit it if it can be made clearer. What I'm struggling with is figuring out how to encapsulate the `compare` logic in a way that can be saved in JSON.

Comment: @mchen.ja You "can't" other than send something that indicates what method to call on the objects (like via reflection). But I wouldn't; the server just needs to know what to do.